# How can I get a list of all my facebook status posts of all time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want the easiest way to download all the status updates I've done since inception of my account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go to https://www.facebook.com/settings
and click on download facebook data at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! That was quick, easy and useful!

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://www.facebook.com/settings, click "Download a copy of your facebook data", down at the bottom of the page.

Or, using the graph API, access `/me/statuses` repeatedly, setting the `until` parameter to the date of the last post you parsed, something like this:

```
# pseudocode:
until = now
do:
    posts = fetch https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?access_token=xxx&until=until
    for each post in posts:
        savepost(post)
        if post.updated_time is before until:
            until = post.updated_time
while posts.length > 0
```

But be aware that some have observed that [some](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/4622096/223594) [posts](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/7341201/223594) mysteriously [go missing](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/7199788/223594) using any API to download all posts.